# How to use TIdNotify

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010, indy

I am trying to write a threaded application in Delphi 2010 using Indy. Both of these are new to me and I am struggling with synchronising the Vcl. I have read about synchronising with the Vcl, using Critical Sections, TThread.Synchronize, TIdNotify etc.
I would like to see an example of how to use TIdnotify. In my case I am trying to update a TreeView from a thread. I have searched the groups/forums, but no success.
Any examples would be very much appreciated.
TIA

Comment: downvote because you didn't mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

```
type
  TMyNotify = class(TidNotify)
  private
    FMyData: string;
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  FormMain.TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, FMyData);
end;
```

And in your Thread:

```
var
  MyNotify: TMyNotify;
begin
  MyNotify := TMyNotify.Create;
  MyNotify.FMyData := 'A new node';
  MyNotify.Notify;
```

Comment: @CMB: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should accept the answer if works. Please refer to [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) of the FAQ for details.